# What is the relation between production, meals and total export price?

Tags: tropico-4

I'm playing Tropico 4 right now, but I'm pretty sure it's the same for all Tropico games. I've finished the normal campain, but I'm still wondering what these numbers are about.

So let's take an example :

- In the "Trade" tab, I can see the "price" of fish (1 ton ? 1 fish ? 1 unit ? something else ?) is : **576** $
- Now I click on my fish farm and I can see the total export so far is : **5372** $
- The total amount of production (units  ? fishes ? tons ? ...?) is **1317**
- The amount of meal is **0**
- The "Stock prod." is **100**

So how are these numbers related ? I would expect that "total export" / "amount of production" = 5372 / 1317 = **4.08** $ would give me a number around the price of a unit, but no, not at all.

Here is a screen cap (french version) :

[image]

Same question for a random farm (Maïs probably means "Corn"), and the price in "Trade" tab is 960 :

[image]

Comment: `"price" of fish (1 ton ? 1 fish ? 1 unit ? something else ?)` — `$ per 100` units of fish(or any other product)

Comment: Well, this explanation do not match with the numbers though : (1317 / 100) * 576 = ~7600 which is very different from 5372. Even if you remove the "100 Stock prod", it does not match. It does not match with the corn as well.

Comment: @Tristan Can you tell with 100% certainty, without knowing the answer, that the answer to this question is the same across all games? If not, please specify only one game, or the question could be closed as too broad.

Comment: Yes, this is core concept, and there are very little tropico questions on Arqade.

Comment: @Tristan, not all products gets exported, as it's explained in Cadence's answer. But price is definetly per 100 units: https://tropico.fandom.com/wiki/Goods_(Tropico_4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Exports" is the cash value of product that *has been exported*. Food products that are eaten (directly from the production building or through a Marketplace) don't count. Products that are turned into something else (e.g. canned fish) don't count. Products that are slated for export but not actually exported yet - being moved around, sitting on the dock waiting for a ship - don't count.

"Production" is the total that's been produced at that building, regardless of what happened to it.

"Meals provided" is the number of times a person has gotten food from the building.

"Output storage" is the amount *currently* sitting in the building, waiting to be hauled somewhere (or eaten).

Also, note that export prices can change over time: from random or scenario-specific events, the effects of your Economic Minister and edicts, the Customs Office, etc. This can lead to a total export amount that's different from what those resources would be worth if exported right now.

Comment: So, to sum it up, you are saying that exports is not equal to (production /100) * price because the price has changed over time, right ? And let's say we are at constant price, what would be the formula to calculate exports ? exports = ((production - output storage - meals) / 100) * price ?

Comment: Production is a combination of the amount exported, output storage, meals provided, materials in storage elsewhere (dock, marketplace, factory), and materials used elsewhere. Not all of those are tracked on the production structure, so it won't always add up neatly.

Comment: Ok. It's a shame they don't display exports in "unit" though in addition to the total price, to make it comparable to production.